# Correct the stored procedure for asp.net

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am writing an advanced search, the procedure works but returns all the selected rows and perform no where check.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[spSearchpatientinfo]
   @user nvarchar(50),
   @accountstart int,
   @accountend int,
   @mnumber nvarchar(20),
   @namefirst nvarchar(30),
   @namelast nvarchar(100),
   @registrationfrom datetime,
   @registrationto datetime,
   @office nvarchar(1),
   @status nvarchar(1)
as
begin
   select   
      pi_reg_id, pi_first_name, pi_last_name, 
      pi_dob, pi_address, pi_city, pi_phone_home,
      pi_phone_work, pi_Email, pi_status 
   from 
      MData.dbo.[Patient info]
   where 
      (pi_insert_user = @user)
      or (@accountstart IS NULL or pi_reg_id >= @accountstart)
      or (@accountend IS NULL or pi_reg_id <= @accountend)
      or (@mnumber IS NULL or pi_phone_home like @mnumber)
      or (@namefirst is null or pi_first_name like @namefirst)
      or (@namelast is null or pi_last_name like @namelast)
      or (@registrationfrom is null or pi_reg_date >= @registrationfrom)
      or (@registrationto is null or pi_reg_date <= @registrationto)
      or (@office is null or pi_office = @office)
      or (@status is null or pi_status = @status)
end
```

Please tell the mistake I am doing

Comment: if ANY of those or statements is true, all results matching that condition will be returned.  So, if you're just looking for a specific user, and the @status is null, it will be returned. even if it's not for the same pi_insert_user.  Perhaps you meant `and` instead of all those outer `or`s...

Comment: Have you tried input that should return nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're checking the variables passed in against null via the subordinate or clauses, I don't think you really mean OR on the outer clause.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[spSearchpatientinfo]
@user nvarchar(50),
@accountstart int,
@accountend int,
@mnumber nvarchar(20),
@namefirst nvarchar(30),
@namelast nvarchar(100),
@registrationfrom datetime,
@registrationto datetime,
@office nvarchar(1),
@status nvarchar(1)
as
begin
select   pi_reg_id,pi_first_name,pi_last_name,pi_dob,pi_address,pi_city,pi_phone_home,pi_phone_work,pi_Email,pi_status from MData.dbo.[Patient info]
where (@user is null or pi_insert_user = @user)
AND (@accountstart IS NULL or pi_reg_id >= @accountstart)
AND (@accountend IS NULL or pi_reg_id <= @accountend)
AND (@mnumber IS NULL or pi_phone_home like @mnumber)
AND (@namefirst is null or pi_first_name like @namefirst)
AND (@namelast is null or pi_last_name like @namelast)
AND (@registrationfrom is null or pi_reg_date >= @registrationfrom)
AND (@registrationto is null or pi_reg_date <= @registrationto)
AND (@office is null or pi_office = @office)
AND (@status is null or pi_status = @status)
end
```

Comment: It does not return anything now.

Comment: is `@User` always filled in or do we need to check for null on it as well?  I guess it would help to know what values are being passed in so we can think though the logic, and ensure you have records that match that criteria...

Comment: @User is always filled with data and all others can be empty or some can be filled depending on users choice.

Comment: say pi_Reg_ID is filled in. if no records are >=accountstart and account end no records should be returned right?  So lets focus on a specific example and ensure we have records matching that example it may help understand where the problem is, because as it stands, so long as nulls are passed in for the @ values, then this appears to me it should be working.

Comment: Using And in outer will result in skiping all the other lines which is not the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SP rewritten to give you what you are looking for, though I see one potential problem.  In the WHERE clause, the "like"s, are your parameters coming in with appended "%"?  If not, they probably won't find anything.

```
ALTER PROC [Dbo].[Spsearchpatientinfo]
    @user NVARCHAR(50), 
    @accountstart INT, 
    @accountend INT, 
    @mnumber NVARCHAR(20), 
    @namefirst NVARCHAR(30), 
    @namelast NVARCHAR(100), 
    @registrationfrom DATETIME, 
    @registrationto DATETIME, 
    @office NVARCHAR(1), 
    @status NVARCHAR(1)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT Pi_Reg_Id, 
        Pi_First_Name, 
        Pi_Last_Name, 
        Pi_Dob, 
        Pi_Address, 
        Pi_City, 
        Pi_Phone_Home, 
        Pi_Phone_Work, 
        Pi_Email, 
        Pi_Status
    FROM Mdata.Dbo.[Patient Info]
    WHERE(Pi_Insert_User = @user)
    AND Pi_Reg_Id >= ISNULL(@accountstart, Pi_Reg_Id)
    AND Pi_Reg_Id <= ISNULL(@accountend, Pi_Reg_Id)
    AND Pi_Phone_Home LIKE ISNULL(@mnumber, Pi_Phone_Home)
    AND Pi_First_Name LIKE ISNULL(@namefirst, Pi_First_Name)
    AND Pi_Last_Name LIKE ISNULL(@namelast, Pi_Last_Name)
    AND Pi_Reg_Date >= ISNULL(@registrationfrom, Pi_Reg_Date)
    AND Pi_Reg_Date <= ISNULL(@registrationto, Pi_Reg_Date)
    AND Pi_Office = ISNULL(@office, Pi_Office)
    AND Pi_Status = ISNULL(@status, Pi_Status);
END;
```